# Streaming data from BigQuery

Tags: apache-spark, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

How to read freshly added data from BigQuery continuously. Is there any existing solution?

Apache spark connector for BigQuery unfortunately does not support streaming.Does GCP has own service for continuous extracting data from BigQuery or any other workaround?

Comment: There is no service to read the freshly added data to BigQuery. It's something about the team is working, to have something similar to CDC feature.

Answer (score 0):

You can create an Apache Beam application and run it via Dataflow. Apache beam supports a couple of languages but the most popular ones are Python and Java API. I would recommend using java API, based on my experience it is more matured compare to Python API.

you can check here for more info -> https://beam.apache.org/documentation/io/built-in/google-bigquery/